# Two questions about elements and subsets in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question 1: if $X$ is a set, are its elements sets? (in ZFC)
I believe the answer is yes. But where is the proof? Is it an axiom?

Question 2: If $X$ is a set, $Y$ is an entity of unknown nature which has elements, is the collection of elements of $X$ which are also elements of $Y$ a set?

If the answer is yes, then is it an axiom of ZFC? Can it be proved using the specification axiom?
Is it true in NBG? When $Y$ is a class?
Thank you all.

Comment: These questions aren't "stupid", but they're not professional research questions and don't belong on this site.  They should be asked at math.stackexchange.

Comment: Technically, everything in ZFC is a set. It is a first order logic, so all things are the same type in first order logic. So there in no entity $Y$ of unknown nature. It is also a set.

Comment: In particular, while you might be introduced to set theory in school as having “a set of dogs,” for example, that intuition is not how sets are used in mathematics. You might ask, “what about numbers?” Well numbers, in set theory, are defined as sets.

Comment: (just to say that the original title used the word "stupid" and I was quoting it)

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: The only thing that exists are sets; the axioms are (in some sense) describing what the rules we can do with sets to create more sets. More accurately, the axioms are about the things that exist.

Answer 2: You described the [axiom of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). This is indeed an axiom (schema) of ZFC.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: Yes, because in ZFC sets are the only kind of thing.

Question 2: Yes. This intersection is a subset of the set $X$, so it exists as a set by an Axiom of Specification.

For NBG, the answers are "Yes, because only sets can be elements of things" and "Yes, but now it's a corollary of the class existence theorem."

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the answer to question 2 is "yes" (by what I would call the "separation" axiom). But I feel the other answers to question 1 are too glib.

Question 1 comes down to "does ZFC allow for the existence of things which aren't sets". It does not because of the axiom of extensionality. If $x$ is not a set then it has no elements, and therefore by extensionality it is the same as the empty set --- so it is a set after all. The axiom of extensionality tells us that everything is *the same* as a set.

Comment: Can you translate "If $x$ is not a set, then it has no elements" into the Language of Set Theory? The purpose behind this probing question is to provide a counter-argument that my response is not "too glib". It is the right amount of "glib"

Comment: No, of course not. Can you translate your comment that "the only thing that exists are sets" into the language of set theory? We are talking in a metalanguage, not the target language.

Comment: and hence we are equally "glib" $\square$.

Comment: No, my answer is better. But I apologize for the perceived slight; I didn't mean it the way you're taking it.

Comment: I have another low priority question. Consider the metalanguage statement "If $x$ is not a set" you used in your argument. What do you mean by "set" here? I interpreted it as the object described by ZFC, but you seem to have another interpretation. I deduced this because you proceed to conclude it "has no elements" without justification. Also (another low priority question), why are you applying the axiom of extensionality to $x$? I thought it wasn't a set. The reason I say "low priority" is because I don't really want an answer. My purpose now is to argue that your answer is too glib.